# Singular vs plural pronunciation

Tags: prononciation

Is there a difference in pronunciation between the following two sentences? In other words, is it possible to tell whether I am talking about one or many colours? Thanks.

> Quelles magnifiques couleurs !
>    Quelle magnifique couleur !

Comment: They are pronounced in exactly the same way. The 3 **s** are silent in the plural sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case, they are pronounced the same way, because the first letters of magnifique and couleur (respectively m and c) are consonants.

But in this example, you hear the difference:

> Quelle étrange abeille !
>
> Quelles étranges abeilles !

Especially because the firsts letters of "étrange" and "abeille" (respectively e and a) are vowels. In French, we make the liaison between a consonant and a vowel. So you hear [z] for the two first 's'.

Have a look here to understand more about liaison: http://www.spellandsound.com/french-liaisons/

Comment: Note that in your example the first liaison is mandatory but the second one is optional and often not done.

Comment: Better link : http://www.spellandsound.com/french-liaisons/.

Comment: Ok @Laure I edit my url.

Answer (score 1):

As said Laure in comment, they  are pronounced in exactly the same way.

You can't distinguish if your are talking about one or many colours.