# Is plural -s in french ever pronounced or subject to liaison?

Tags: orthographe

In French the plural articles, and verb agreement show when nouns are plural, yet an ''-s'' is added in spelling.

Singular: Je mange une pomme/Je mange la pomme/La pomme est rouge/La pomme a X.

Plural: Je mange des pomme**s**/Je mange les pomme**s**/La pommes sont rouge**s**/Les pomme**s** ont X.

Questions:

Is this a prescriptive spelling ''feature'' or addition, or is it historical?

Is the ''-s'' always mute, and purely an orthographic convention, or is it sometimes pronounced on its own and/or able to invoke liaison (as last example sentence)?

If the s is never pronounced, as if it's not even there, then it will help me when reading unfamiliar texts to know that I should just ignore it.

Comment: There's easily available information on how and when to pronounce the plural *s*. Have you looked at it? For example, the article on [French liaison on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)), or [When to pronounce the plural -s](http://www.french-linguistics.co.uk/grammar/plural.shtml). And partial answers on French Language: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/8955/358, https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19306/singular-vs-plural-pronunciation, https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19306/singular-vs-plural-pronunciation

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the information provided by LPH, here's what Ferdinand Brunot, the linguist (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Brunot), had to say about liaison between nouns and adjectives :

« L'*s* du pluriel s'entend dans les liaisons, où il se prononce /z/ et non /s/, quand l'adjectif précède le nom :

- de grands hommes /dəgrɑ̃zɔm/

Mais Thomas Corneille (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Corneille), quand l'adjectif est placé après le nom, exige que l'on « mange l'*s* finale »:

- des tromperies inutiles /detʀɔ̃pʀiinytil/

Telle est, en dépit des Conservatoires (et de la radio), la prononciation correcte dans la bonne société française depuis la fin du XVIIe siècle. »

"Plural *s* is heard in liaisons, where it is sounded as /z/ and not /s/, when the adjective comes before the noun.

- de grands hommes /dəgrɑ̃zɔm/

However, Thomas Corneille, when the adjective comes after the noun, demanded that "final *s* be swallowed".

- des tromperies inutiles /detʀɔ̃pʀiinytil/

This has been, in spite of drama schools (and radio broadcasting), the correct pronunciation in French high society since the end of the 17th century."

Brunot's remark may not apply any longer, but then again it might; in any event, it'll come in handy if you ever need to read out loud the conversations that take place in Mme de Villeparisis' salon in Proust's *Le côté de Guermantes*.

Comment: As well as nouns and adjectives there are some other words that take a plural -s even though some of them are a bit irregular and there is disagreement about their grammatical classification. These are *mes, tes, ses, nos, vos, ces, ils, elles, elles* (strong), *leurs*. I think most of these liaise but I'm not sure about the last. Perhaps someone could tell me.

Comment: @DavidRobinson All the words you mention, and also "nous and "vous", liaise with words starting with a vowel sound.  So does "leurs", it's the only way to distinguish orally "leur ami" /lœrami/, "their friend" from "leurs amis" /lœrzami/, "their friends".  Liaison for this class of words is not optional but mandatory.

Comment: Thank you, @petitrien,  for the information, including *nous* and *vous*. I did not include these as I didn't think the *s* was a "plural *-s*" as there is no singular form without the *s*. Does anyone know why these words end in *s*?

Answer (score 1):

**I**

On trouve la réponse suivante sur le [web](https://forum.lokanova.net/viewtopic.php?t=26675#p368552) (1/ et 2/);

> 1/ Dans les langues latines, c'est le -s du pluriel latin à l'accusatif (objet direct), qui est le cas qui est resté le plus longtemps (le plus fréquent avec le nominatif du sujet) et qui a donné en général la forme actuelle du mot.

Un compte-rendu plus approfondi

> 2/ C'est un tout petit peu plus compliqué que ce que vous avez dit jusqu'ici
>
> En français
>
> En bas-latin, le système désinentiel est en ruine, mais il continue à peu près d'exister au nominatif et à l'accusatif. Or, dans le domaine gallo-roman et ibéro-roman (mais non pas italo-romans ni daço-roman), on observe dès l'époque latine une généralisation de la désinence -as au nominatif pluriel au lieu de -ae (j'en ai vue une récemment sur une inscription du musée de Lyon) : c'est une particularité de cette zone, et elle est d'ailleurs très ancienne : dès l'époque de Cicéron, les grammairien témoignaient de cet "accusativus pro nominativo" dans le latin des "rustici", c'est-à-dire des paysans, sans doute ceux qui n'étaient pas originellement latinophones.
>
> Bref : si l'on ajoute à cela le fait que les quatrième et cinquième déclinaisons ont disparu, on a un système pluriel qui est le suivant :
>
> N. -as
>   A. -as
>
> N. -i
>    A. -os
>
> N. -es
>   A. -es
>
> Donc, pour les mots féminins de la première déclinaison et pour les mots de la troisième, le -s est déjà la marque de pluriel sans distinction de cas, et passe tel quel en français (illlas rosas > les roses, illos patres > les peres). En revanche, pour les mots (masculins) de la deuxième, la différence de cas est encore visible en ancien français :
>
> Sujet = li mur (< illi muri)
>    Objet = les murs (< illos muros)
>
> Mais cette catégorie est isolée par rapport aux deux autres et le système entier finit par disparaître vers le 14e siècle.

**II**

La [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3550) donne les indications suivantes;

> La liaison est facultative entre le nom pluriel et l'adjectif ou le complément du nom qui le suit.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - On a entendu plusieurs chansons entraînantes. [ʃãsɔ̃zãtʀɛnãt] (chan-son-zan-trè-nante) ou [ʃãsɔ̃ãtʀɛnãt] (chan-son-an-trè-nante)
> - Luc a raconté des histoires effrayantes. [dezistwaʀzɛfʀɛjãt] (dé-zis-touar-zè-frè-yante) ou [dezistwaʀɛfʀɛjãt] (dé-zis-toua-rè-frè-yante)
> - Les personnes en question n'ont pas réagi. [pɛʀsɔnzãkɛstjɔ̃] (pèr-sonn-zan-kes-tion) ou [pɛʀsɔnãkɛstjɔ̃] (pèr-sonn-nan-kes-tion)
> - Les gens en deuil portent souvent du noir. [ʒãzãdœj] (jan-zan-deuil) ou [ʒããdœj] (jan-an-deuil)
> - Virginie aime les bateaux à voile. [batozavwal] (ba-to-za-voual) ou [batoavwal] (ba-to-a-voual)
>
> La liaison est facultative entre le nom pluriel en fonction sujet et le verbe qui le suit; cette liaison est propre à la langue soutenue.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - Mes amis étaient tous présents. [mezamizetɛ] (mé-za-mi-zé-tè) ou [mezamietɛ] (mé-za-mi-é-tè)
> - Charles pensait que ces couleurs allaient bien ensemble. [kulœʀzalɛ] (kou-leur-za-lè) ou [kulœʀalɛ] (kou-leur-a-lè)